# In Crystal Report load Last record only from For Loop

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i am using the crystal report in c# web application. there is a problem that the crystal report load last record from For loop.

i stores the code of product in for loop as code. and according to that single or multiple code the the crystal report shows info. of that product.

i use....

```
for (int i = 0; i < code.Length; i++)
    {
        string str = "select crbal*-1 as crbal, glname, contprsn, refby, glphone1, glcity, glphone2, email, crlimit, restorddueamt  from db1.dbo.glmast WHERE drgroup='A3402' and crbal<>0 and glcode="+code[i]+ "";

        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(str, con2);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ad.Fill(ds);

        path = Server.MapPath("ERP_REPORT_MAIN.rpt");
        cr = new ReportDocument();
        cr.Load(path);

        cr.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr;
    }
```

if, there is two code in for loop it display last record only. please Help Me.

Thanks and Regards...
Mitesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would revise the code, and make also some slight efficiency improvments:

```
string query = "select crbal*-1 as crbal, glname, contprsn, refby, glphone1, glcity,    glphone2, email, crlimit, restorddueamt  from db1.dbo.glmast WHERE drgroup='A3402' and crbal<>0 and glcode in (

for (int i = 0; i < code.Length; i++)
{
    query += code[i];
    if (i != code.Length -1)
        query += ","
    else
        query += ")";
}

SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(str, con2);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ad.Fill(ds);

path = Server.MapPath("ERP_REPORT_MAIN.rpt");
cr = new ReportDocument();
cr.Load(path);

cr.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr;
```